# How can I ask for entry data in tkinter in python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How can I ask for entry data in tkinter? I tried using standard if statement but it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

```
from tkinter import *

class Search(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.search = Button(self, text="Search", command=self.search_button)
        self.search.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.entry.pack(side=LEFT)

    def search_button(self):
        (self.entry.get())

if Entry=="example1":
    print ("example1")

app = Search()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an indentation problem. Try this:

```
    def search_button(self):
        if self.entry.get() == "example1":
            print("example1")
```

I've indented this code block an extra level to indicate that it should be a `Search` method rather than a global function.

Comment: it gives back error: 
if self.entry.get() == 'example1':
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Sorry; I usually have most of my `tkinter` logic inside the main GUI class. Refer to that instance of your class with `app` instead of `self`.

Comment: No problem thanks for help. It still returns same error unfortunately: if app.entry.get() == 'example1':
NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Comment: On close inspection, your indentation was not as expected. Put the `if` statement inside the `search_button` function.